# Assigning row & column to a 2D array using an array's length

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have data that I am feeding into an array, and I'd like to assign the row & column of a 2D array using simply the length of an array.

For instance, if my array has a length of 18, how can I make sure that the row and column of the 2D array is `2darray[3][6]`, as well as making sure it isn't `[2][9]`?

I started a really simple for loop to find the factors of my array length but I quickly found that that might be too complicated and there ought to be a simpler way.

This is what I did:

```
for( int i = 11; i > 0; i-- ) {
    if( 18 % i == 0 ) {
        System.out.print( i + "   " );
    } 
}
```

Output:

```
9  6  3  2  1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the criteria you're using to determine the dimensions of the 2d array? Why is `2darray[3][6]` ok but `2darray[2][9]` unacceptable?

Comment: If your global 1-d array is all you've got, you can't possibly choose between the possible equivalent 2-d arrays unless the data has some visible constraints. @Michael0x2a asked the right question, please explain to us. **Are you looking for the most "squarish" 2-d array?**

Comment: Why are you getting your data as a 1-d array in the first place? Do you control what you receive?

Comment: Also, why does your loop start at 11 instead of 18? `2darray[18][1]` would be glad to be a candidate too! :D

Comment: You need to know one of the dimension of the 2D array upfront. So you can do it based on the *expected* `2darray.length`.

Comment: @joffrey yes, I am looking for the most squarish 2d array... Any ideas?

Comment: @Michael0x2a I'm looking for the most square factor.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking for the most squarish array, you can use the loop you posted here to build an array of possible dimensions, but start at the 1-d array's length to get all possible values.

At that point:

- if you have an even number of values, choose the 2 values in the center for the most squarish 2-d array. You still have the choice as to whether take the biggest dimension first or not.
- if you have an odd number of values, choose the value in the center for the most squarish 2-d array, the 2 dimensions are equal

Here is how I would do this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array1D = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 };
        //int[] array1D = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };

        int[][] array2D = to2DArray(array1D);
    }

    public static int[][] to2DArray(int[] array1D) {
        // will contain the possible dimensions for the 2D array
        ArrayList<Integer> dims = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= array1D.length; i++) {
            if (array1D.length % i == 0) {
                dims.add(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dims.toArray(new Integer[dims.size()])));

        int nbValues = dims.size();
        // use a central value for the most squarish 2D array
        int sizeX = dims.get(nbValues / 2);
        // set up the other dimension
        int sizeY;
        if (nbValues % 2 == 0) {
            // the 1-d array was not special, take the other central value
            sizeY = dims.get(nbValues / 2 - 1);
        } else {
            // the 1-d array length was a perfect square, take the same value
            sizeY = sizeX;
        }
        System.out.println("sizeX=" + sizeX + " sizeY=" + sizeY);

        // create the array and fill it with data
        int[][] array2D = new int[sizeX][sizeY];
        copyData(array1D, array2D);
        return array2D;
    }

    public static void copyData(int[] array1D, int[][] array2D) {
        // TODO take the data from array1D and copy it into array2D
    }
}
```